# Getting a running error while running some code to import X3D into Java

Tags: java, netbeans, x3d

I'm trying to make a project that loads X3D files into Java and for Java to display them, I'm using Xj3D to do this but when I run the code, I seem to be getting an error. I've downloaded all the jars that are listed [here](http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/xj3d_application.html). I've made a library that's called 'Xj3D' and in the project properties, in the libraries section, I've put the Xj3D library and in the VM options, I've put `-Xmx450M -Djava.library.path='C:\Users\matt\Downloads\xj3d-sai_2.0.0.jar'` and the code that I have in java is:

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","MEDIUM");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","MEDIUM");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","LOW");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.web3d.ogl.browser.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Component browserComponent = (Component)  x3dComponent.getImplementation();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(browserComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"test.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And I've put the test.x3dv file in the project folder. The test.x3dv code is as follows:

```
#X3D V3.0 utf8

PROFILE Interactive

DEF TS TimeSensor {
  cycleInterval 3
  loop TRUE
}

DEF TG Transform {
  rotation 0 1 0 0
  children Shape {
    geometry Box {}
    appearance Appearance {
      material DEF MAT Material {
        diffuseColor 1 0 0
      }
    }
  }
}

DEF OI OrientationInterpolator {
  key [ 0 0.5 1 ]
  keyValue [
     0 1 0 0
     0 1 0 3.14
     0 1 0 6.28
  ]
}

ROUTE TS.fraction_changed TO OI.set_fraction
ROUTE OI.value_changed TO TG.rotation
```

When I press the run button in Netbeans, I get the following runtime error:

```
No skin defined in xj3d-skin.properties
Producing default properties.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/j3d/aviatrix3d/DrawableSurface
    at org.web3d.ogl.browser.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.createComponent(X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.java:249)
    at  org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:252)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:43)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.j3d.aviatrix3d.DrawableSurface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: is your jars in the class path?? -cp .;C:\Users\matt\Downloads\xj3d-sai_2.0.0.jar

Comment: Yeah I've put that in the VM options and I've got the same error when I ran the code

Comment: I dont know what happens with this X3 but it says "The following jars are always required: " and then a list of things - so that means all the jars must appear on the cp line

Comment: @gpasch I've put all the jars on that required list in the `xj3d-sai-2.0.0` folder which is why I've put the `-cp .;C:\Users\matt\Downloads\xj3d-sai_2.0.0.jar` as the folder name is xj3d-sai_2.0.0.jar

Comment: And when I've checked the libraries tab under the project, it lists all the jars that's on that site.